# Let $M$ be a finitely generated $R$-module and $I \subset R$ an ideal such that $IM = M$. If $M'$ is a particular submodule, does $IM '= M'$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

> Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring, $I$ an ideal, and $M$ a finitely generated $R$-module with generators $\{m_1, \ldots, m_n\}$; suppose further that $IM = M$. Let $M'$ be the submodule of $M$ generated by $\{m_2, \ldots, m_n\}$. I would like to prove that $IM' = M'$.

$IM' \subseteq M'$ is of course trivial, following from the closure of submodules under scalar multiplication by elements of $R$; I am having some difficulty proving containment in the opposite direction.

Comment: Are you familiar with Nakayama's lemma?

Comment: Yes; the problem I am attacking is an alternate proof of Nakayama's lemma.

Comment: In fact, $IM'=M'$ holds for *any* submodule $M'$ of $M$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $M=IM$, we can write $m_1=a_1m_1+a_2m_2+\dots+a_nm_n$, for $a_i\in I$.  Rearranging terms, we find $(1-a_1)m_1\in IM'$.  Now use this to show that $(1-a_1)m_i\in IM'$ for $i=2,\dots,n$ as well.  Since $a_1\in I$, conclude that in fact $m_i\in IM'$ for $i=2,\dots,n$.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you on "now use this to show". Do you mean $(1-a_i) m_i \in IM'$?

Comment: No, I mean what I wrote.  If you're still stuck, try writing $m_i$ as an element of $IM$ and multiply both sides by $1-a_1$.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially a corollary of Nakayama's Lemma. This states that $IM=M$ is equivalent to $(1-a)M=0$ for some $a \in I$. Now, if $M'$ is *any* submodule of $M$, it follows $(1-a)M'=0$ and hence $IM'=M'$.

Comment: Right, but as commented, this is being used to _prove_ Nakayama.

Comment: Right. Forgot about that.